# Ubuntu 18.04.3 and Nvidia 435 driver, fan not working

Tags: 18.04, gpu-driver, nvidia-geforce, automatic

I am trying to get my GPU fully functional just by installing the Nvidia driver via Ubuntu 'third party drivers' on a clean Ubuntu installation.
Laptop: ASUS zenbook with an Intel i7 and Nvidia MX150 GPU.

I have tried the latest of the three in this menu, version 435, but also version 430. 
Both of these drivers install successfully and recognize the GPU. Nvidia-settings are available and I can see Nvidia processes running with lsmod and not any of the open-source driver 'Nouveau' processes.
I have disabled secure boot just to make sure this is not the problem because of enrolling a new key and stuff, but with no effect.

The problem: no fan is spinning. The machine gets very hot when playing a game for instance.

The strange thing is, with a fresh install of this driver the fan works perfectly. But after a second reboot it's not working at any time.

```
nvidia-smi:

Thu Nov 28 21:49:46 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 435.21       Driver Version: 435.21       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce MX150       Off  | 00000000:02:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   51C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    218MiB /  2002MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1370      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           137MiB |
|    0      1558      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          80MiB |
|    0      2325      G   gnome-control-center                           1MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

nvidia-settings

GPU at BusId 0x2 doesn't have a supported video decoder

** Message: 22:15:23.303: PRIME: Requires offloading

** Message: 22:15:23.303: PRIME: is it supported? yes